# How to handle OAuth2 refresh_token for sessionless login?

Tags: session-management, oauth, local-storage

I'm working on a single-page sessionless app with OAuth2 login and a "Remember me" checkbox. When the user checks "Remember me" on login I store the refresh token in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) for 30 days. It feels a little insecure to just leave it there until the user logs in again. What is the best practice for persisting refresh tokens in a sessionless environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee they will remain logged in for 30 days then that is the most secure way to do it. And yes, it's not secure at all. It's a usability / security decision you will have to make depending on the risk. You can do something like encrypt it but you would have to store the key in local storage too so it's not any safer.

Comment: I was thinking I could store the key on the server and decrypt it before I make a request for a new access_token.

Comment: Yes but if somebody were to get access to the encrypted token, couldn't they just use that to log in if the key used to decrypt it is on the server? they would just log in and your server would automatically decrypt it. You would need to tie the user to an encryption key, but it's a circular reference. How could you ensure that the user with the encrypted token is authorized to access the Key to decrypt it

Comment: Yes, these are the kind of questions I had. Encryption seems a little redundant I guess.

Comment: Yea there isnt really a way to make this any more secure if this is the route you choose.